# systemd before,after,requires all not working like expected

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, nfs, zfs

I have an nfs mount on a debian12 system running systemd252, i need this to be mounted at startup before zfs but after `network-online.target`, so i tried using `/etc/fstab` but that keeps loading before `network-online.target` (even when using x-systemd.before= etc). I've also tried putting a script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/nfs` that mounts nfs, but zfs loads before that.

So, i tried making a mount service with systemd;

```
# /etc/systemd/system/nfs.mount
[Unit]
Description=nfs
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=local-fs.target umount.target zfs-import.target
After=swap.target network-online.target
Requires=network-online.target #it doesn't work with and without this line

[Mount]
What=0.0.0.0:/ # generic info
Where=/nfs
Type=nfs
Options=ro,async,nfsvers=4,nosuid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This seems to load before `network-online.target` because it errors and says: "mount.nfs: Network is unreachable", i've also tried making multiple other services but before,after and requires never seem to work. How would i achieve loading network,nfs,zfs in order?

EDIT: It seems like `network-online.target` reports being reached too early, `nfs.mount` does get started right after, which means that "after=" works. I tried adding a delay with `ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/sleep 10` but this delays it for 2 whole minutes.

EDIT2: I fixed it by changing the service;

```
# /etc/systemd/system/mount-nfs.service
[Unit]
Description=Mount nfs after network but before docker
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=docker.service
After=network-online.target remote-fs.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/sleep 15
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mount 0.0.0.0:/ /nfs
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/zfs mount -a

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Added `after=remote-fs.target` because of [this blog post](https://blog.agchapman.com/auto-mounting-network-file-systems-with-systemd/),
`wants=network-online.target` because of [this doc](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/),
and replaced `before=zfs-import.target` by just mounting with `zfs mount -a`

So in the end, the main post title was solved. (I'm not posting an answer to my own question because i technically worked around the problem instead of fully fixing it)